# Socket.io not sending emit

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am making an Agar.io clone with Node-js and Socket.io. When the dot reaches the end of the map (so the x or y is greater than 10000 or less than 0), it dies. 
So the first time after I start the server, it works perfectly, but than the server does not emits the die message.

I have tried deleting the socket, because I first thaught that it only happens if I refresh the page (maybe the socket id does not change), but I figured out, that after the first death message, none of the future sockets will send it again.

The die message (server side):

```
setInterval(function() {

    socket.emit("players", players); //sending infos about all players

    if(playerID === undefined || players[playerID] === undefined) { //checking if the player is joined to the match

      return;

    }

    if(players[playerID].x < 0 || players[playerID].x > 10000 || players[playerID].y < 0 || players[playerID].y > 10000) { //checking if it should be dead

      socket.emit("death"); //sending death message
      players.splice(playerID, 1); //removing player from players object

    }

  }, 1000 / 60);
```

The die listener (client side):

```
socket.on("death", function() {

    $("body").append('<div class="join-modal"><div class="container">You died! Rejoin the game:<br><input type="text" placeholder="Name"><button>Join!</button><p class="error"></p></div></div>'); //adding a rejoin modal
    player.alive = false; //client side alive tracking
    console.log("died");

  });
```

Comment: Have you checked if the death condition is met on your node server with a log?

Comment: @cillierscharl yes